# Which version do I need to download?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, windows-8, 32-bit

I'm currently running a Windows 7 computer, but it says I have a 64-bit OS, and I'm confused as to whether or not I need to download the 32-bit version of Ubuntu, or the 64-bit, since it says to download the 64-bit version if I have a Windows 8 logo.

Comment: If you have Windows 8, then you have a 64-bit compatible system. so download the 64-bit version. What kind of hardware do you have?

Answer (score 0):

My computer is Windows 7 64 bit. Let me tell you that I consider W8 is a stupid version of Microsoft.
Second point: I downloaded Ubuntu 13.04 (64 bit) and burned on a DVD. It's a question to modify how to start the computer: Just press the F2 key and select to boot first of all the disk and the HDD later.
Therefore with the DVD the computer starts and asks where are you?, for example.
Once wihout the disk at the moment of rebooting appears several alternatives: Ubuntu and Windows. 
It runs very well.